# How to call SysMsgProc from java?

Tags: java

I want to trace user activities on windows OS. 
The windows documentation says : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589.aspx 
But i am unable to use **SysMsgProc** in java. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Trace user activities?  [The Lives of Others](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405094/)?

Comment: User activities on windows **operating system**.